# powershell script command that keeps on running the script even on remote user disconnets

Tags: powershell-3.0

Can anyone help me with running a powershell script that doesn't stop/exit even when current user logout or disconnects from remote system.

I am familiar with following pattern but it does miss its value when remote user disconnects.

```
  powershell -file "$path_to_file\sample.ps1"
```

Comment: Command should normally keep running if you only disconnect a session. If you want them to run independently of a user session you need to create a scheduled task with the setting "run whether user is logged on or not".

Comment: Could you give more insights on how you are running this in a remote machine ?